# Track user motion and build the path using Google ARCore

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arcore, sceneform

I am trying to build user path finder on android using ARCore library. I followed the example code given by **Sceneform UX HelloSceneformActivity**. I modified it and is able to display the arrow using the **AnchorNode** and **TransformableNode** in left, right, and forward direction.

Now all the direction are given at once so, the directions are becoming messy on the screen. What I want is, when user reaches certain point and then there is left or right turn at that point it should build (display) the next path.